# How to install GNU Make Windows

Tags: makefile, gnu

I downloaded and unzipped the file to folder c:\make-4.2.

The install instructions I have seen suggest that I just type "make install" and the installation will start.

I don't see that "make" file there. I tried it from the directory and got an error that the command is not recognized.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what install instructions you are referring to, but certainly not the ones that come with GNU make itself.  There's no platform where you can simply untar the source code and type "make install" with no other steps, and certainly not on Windows.

If you're trying to build GNU make from downloaded source on Windows, you should read the README.W32 file that comes with the source code and follow the instructions there.

Comment: While its not a good idea, and not recommended, "make && sudo make install" will work on most UNIX systems, including Linux. (Its uninstalling or upgrading later that become a problem) . Windows... I have no idea. Probably not.

Comment: The OP is trying to build GNU Make itself, not use GNU Make to build some other package.  You definitely can't just run `make && sudo make install`, even on Linux: like all GNU source packages you first have to run `./configure` to configure the software for whatever system you have.

Answer (score 0):

From a command line, such as CMD.exe or git bash, run this:

winget install GnuWin32.Make

(did you know windows has a package manager? Me neither. Now you do.)

Now it is installed in c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe

Adding that directory, "c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin"  to your
path in windows is a separate question, but most people would want do that.

More detailed instruction, including adding the path to your environment:
https://www.technewstoday.com/install-and-use-make-in-windows/